# Haskell map function, return a list without zeroes

Tags: haskell

Here is my code:

```
x = map classify[1..20] 

classify :: Int -> Int 
classify n 
         | n `mod` 2 == 0 = n + 2
         | otherwise = 0
```

When calling x it returns a list

```
[0,4,0,6,0,8,0,10,0,12,0,14,0,16,0,18,0,20,0,22]
```

**How can I specify that I want just numbers that are not 0 is list:**

```
[4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22]
```

Comment: Well what is wrong with just saying `x = [4,6..22]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) for this. This function takes a function (of type `a -> Bool` called the "predicate") and a list, and it generates a list of values where the predicate is satisfied (returns `True` for that element).

So you can filter out zeros with:

```
filter (0 /=) mylist
```

For your sample list, this generates:

```
Prelude> filter (0 /=) [0,4,0,6,0,8,0,10,0,12,0,14,0,16,0,18,0,20,0,22]
[4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22]
```

That being said, for this *specific* case, you can save yourself the trouble from generating such elements in the first place by making "hops of 2":

```
x = map classify [2, 4..20]
```

This thus will `map` a list that contains `[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]`, all the elements in between will - given your function - be mapped to zero. By making hops of two, we avoid calculating these values in the first place. But this of course only works for this specific case.